# Understanding the approach used in flipping binary string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm, data-structures

**Details:**

Given a binary string `s` that contains only `"0"` and `"1".` You are also given an array query with the following operations:

1. "Count" - The answer to this query is the number of 1s in the binary string.
2. "Flip" - Flip the substring `[0, idx]` so that "0" -> "1" and "1" -> "0" and `idx` is the first `"0"` in the binary string. You are guaranteed that flip operation will only be called when there is at least one "0". The answer to the query is `idx.`

**Constraints:**

```
1 <= s.length() <= 100000 (1e5)
1 <= query.length <= 100000 (1e5)
```

**Example:**

```
s = "01110"
q = ["count", "count", "flip", "count", "count"]
Ans = [3, 3, 0, 4, 4]

s = "000"
q = ["flip", "count", "count"]
Ans = [0, 1, 1]
```

**Explanation:**

```
count -> there are 3 "1"
count -> there are 3 "1"
flip -> the first 0 is at index 0, now the string becomes "11110"
count -> there are 4 "1"
count -> there are 4 "1"
```

**Approach to solve the problem:**

Say `s="0110"`, let us `flip it 4 times`, we will have

```
1110
0001
1001
0101
```

reverse the above binary forms, we have:

```
111
1000
1001
1010
```

i.e. 7,8,9,10 in decimal form, so each flipping will add 1 to the decimal form.

1. Since `len(q)<10 ** 5`, we will `add at most 10 ** 5.` So, generally, flipping will only affect, say, the first 32 characters of S. convert `S[0:32]` to a decimal num for quick operations.
2. Check how many flips we can have for S[0:32] before having `32 '1's`, -----> `2^32-1 - int(S[0:32][::-1])`
3. If step 1 is enough to cover all flips in Q, `convert S[0:32] to a decimal num`, and the remaining substring `S[32:]` will no longer change.
4. If step 1 is not enough to cover all flips in Q, find the `first '0' in S[32:]`, flip S once: `S='00000....1'+S[i:]`
5. After step 3, `convert S[0:32]` to `0`, and the remaining substring S[32:] will no longer change.

Solution:

```
def flip_index(number): # number must be smaller than 2^30
    string = bin(number)[2:][::-1]
    string += "0"*(30-len(string))
    j = 0
    while j < 30:
        if string[j] == "0":
            return j
        j += 1
     

def flipcount(s, q):
    if len(s) < 30:
        s += "0"*(30-len(s))
    number = int(s[0:30][::-1],2)
    count = s[30:].count("1")
    result = []
    if number == (1<<30) - 1:
        first_zero_index = 30
        while first_zero_index < len(s) and s[first_zero_index] == "1":
            first_zero_index += 1
    
    for query in q:
        if query == "flip":
            if number == (1<<30) - 1:
                result.append(first_zero_index)
                number = 0
                count = s[first_zero_index+1:].count("1") + 1
            else:
                result.append(flip_index(number))
                number += 1
        else:
            if number == (1<<30) - 1:
                result.append(count + 30)
            else:
                result.append(count + bin(number)[2:].count('1'))
    return result
```

**Question/Doubts:**

My doubt is mainly related to understanding the "Approach" section steps 1-4.

- How the conclusion that `flipping will only affect, say, the first 32 characters of S` is made?
- What is the idea behind `2^32-1 - int(S[0:32][::-1])?`
- How are we concluding that `the remaining substring S[32:] will no longer change.`?

Comment: *What is the idea behind" --- the idea is wrong. Flipping may affect all 10**5 characters, not just the first 32. "Since len(q)<10 ** 5, we will add at most 10 ** 5" is the first false statement.

Comment: the given code is passing all the test cases though.

Comment: It works because you can only flip more than 30 bits precisely once out of the 1e5 possible flips. In order to flip more than 30 bits, the first 30 bits in the array must all be 1's. After that special-case flip, the first 30 bits are all zero, and you can never get them to be all 1's again.

Comment: You'll notice that before the query loop, the code looks for the first zero that's **after** the 30th bit. Inside the query loop, it checks whether the number has reached `(1 << 30) - 1` (which indicates that the first 30 bits in the array are all 1). When that happens, the code performs the special case flip that can flip any number of bits.

Comment: Even though it might not be completely correct, still I need some help to fully understand the approach given in steps1-4. Right now, I can't seem to wrap my head around it

Comment: There's a good chance that it is completely correct. But steps 1-4 don't match the code you've posted. Those steps contain the number 32 numerous times. There are no 32's in the code.

Comment: but the logic is same as it is mentioned in the approach. Instead of 32, it is using 30, and that is the only difference.

Comment: Sorry it works because query length is limited. You can affect more than 30 bits once in 2**30 flips, but since there are less queries than that, it cannot happen more than once.

Comment: "but the logic is same as it is mentioned in the approach. " --> formula is correct, code is not. | " query length is limited. " <-- this is the code/computer limit, not the formula. | "doubt is mainly related to understanding the "Approach" section steps 1-4." <--- the same formula CAN be executed as operation on a string instead of operation on a long int, right? (and it should be able to lift off the 2**30 limit too)